# PHP how to get local IP of system

Tags: php, ip-address

I need to get local IP of computer like 192.*....
Is this possible with PHP?

I need IP address of system running the script, but I do not need the external IP, I need his local network card address.

Answer (score 131):

### From CLI

#### PHP < 5.3.0

`$localIP = getHostByName(php_uname('n'));`

#### PHP >= 5.3.0

`$localIP = getHostByName(getHostName());`

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me and that avoids calling shells, operating system commands and all sorts of stuff that can open security holes or raise odd issues later.

Comment: Best response usually comes with simplicity. Like that.

Comment: @andras.tim I like simple answers , however when I ran your script it's not returning my machine's IP address, it's returning the IP address used in my virtual machine..what could be the problem though?

Comment: just be aware, this approach relies on DNS correctly resolving whatever the system's hostname is set to. that will not always be the case.

Comment: In cloud hosting environment, this may not return expected result. Because every host has more than 2 IPs.

Comment: This returns 127.0.0.1 for me, even though there are eth0 and wlan0 devices present, which have their own DHCP-assigned addresses.

Comment: Same here. Returns 127.0.1.1. Not sure whom it worked for.

Comment: @FractalSpace, your `/etc/hosts` file is not configured properly. You should check the DNS >> IP resolution with e.g.: `ping HOSTNAME`

Comment: @andras.tim yes, that was my issue. I am still sticking with `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` solution.
(BTW you mean `ping $HOSTNAME`)

Answer (score 65):

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
```

Comment: Clarification: a computer can have several IP addresses. This variable is HTTP-only and contains the IP address the virtual host is running at. Given how vague the question is, it's hard to say if this is the expected answer.

Comment: I think this is correct, because you need always the asigned ip, the one is responding you. If not, you must use @andras.tim's asnwers, because tells you the main ip of system.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, because my servers are behind a load balancer so `getHostName` doesn't return the sites domain name.

Comment: This doesn't work if you are running inside a docker container

Answer (score 36):

This is an old post, but get it with this:

```
function getLocalIp()
{ return gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`)); }
```

For example:

```
die( getLocalIp() );
```

Found it on another site, do not remove the trim command because otherwise you will get the computers name.

BACKTICKS (The special quotes):
It works because PHP will attempt to run whatever it's between those "special quotes" (backticks) as a shell command and returns the resulting output.

```
gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`));
```

Is very similar (but much more efficient) than doing:

```
$exec = exec("hostname"); //the "hostname" is a valid command in both windows and linux
$hostname = trim($exec); //remove any spaces before and after
$ip = gethostbyname($hostname); //resolves the hostname using local hosts resolver or DNS
```

Comment: @paul: Because of the special quotes, when you using normal quotes it doesn't work for some reason and when you remove the trim command it even doesn't work. It sounds weird i know. It is not nice to downvote the answer for that. Read the answer.

Comment: Backticks (`) are called the execution operator in PHP. What your doing in the first code block is almost the same as the exec command.

See [PHP: Execution Operators - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Comment: Not really the best idea. It is possible and valid for `gethostbyname` to return a loopback IP (e.g. 127.0.0.1) for the host machine.

Comment: This help me a lot , I thought there would be simple PHP function like **$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];** which didn't work, but this solution worked for me !!!

Answer (score 35):

A reliable way to get the external IP address of the local machine would be to query the routing table, although we have no direct way to do it in PHP.

However we can get the system to do it for us by binding a UDP socket to a public address, and getting its address:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_connect($sock, "8.8.8.8", 53);
socket_getsockname($sock, $name); // $name passed by reference

// This is the local machine's external IP address
$localAddr = $name;
```

`socket_connect` will not cause any network traffic because it's an UDP socket.

Comment: This answer is WAY better than the others. Any reliance on the $_SERVER array is dependent on this running under Apache. This idea also works on a cron job. I'm using it to only execute certain functions if a server is running on the staging or the production LAN. Perfect!

Comment: This is an elegent answer.  I adapted it in in a script managing docker containers to get the ip of my host on the docker network:
`$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_connect($sock, $this->getDockerMachineIp(), 53);`

Comment: It is more portable I guess. Also, it is important to mention `sockets` module should be installed and enabled on PHP.

Comment: yes, thankyou very much @Arnaud Le Blanc, its very helpful for me, i got my IP address with this technique

Answer (score 23):

try this (if your server is Linux):

```
$command="/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'";
$localIP = exec ($command);
echo $localIP;
```

Comment: Not absolutely right. There is no guarantee `eth0` is the appropriate interface.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for me. Being able to set the interface helped!

Comment: In my case (local IP in WiFi local network) I had to specify `wlan0` instead of `eth0` and to replace `'inet addr:'` with `'inet adr:'`, possibly due to the locale used on my system (fr_FR). Other than that, this answer was the solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Well actually `'inet adr:'` worked in my terminal (french locale), but in the PHP script `'inet addr:'` was the correct value (english locale, I guess).

Answer (score 16):

Depends what you mean by local:

If by local you mean the address of the server/system executing the PHP code, then there are still two avenues to discuss.  If PHP is being run through a web server, then you can get the server address by reading `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`.  If PHP is being run through a command line interface, then you would likely have to shell-execute `ipconfig` (Windows) / `ifconfig` (*nix) and grep out the address.

If by local you mean the remote address of the website visitor, but not their external IP address (since you specifically said 192.*), then you are out of luck. The whole point of NAT routing is to hide that address. You cannot identify the local addresses of individual computers behind an IP address, but there are some tricks (user agent, possibly mac address) that can help differentiate if there are multiple computers accessing from the same IP.

Comment: And last but not least, ipconfig/ifconfig will most likely return several IP addresses: because a computer does not normally have one single address. Great answer.

Comment: yes the whole point of NAT is to hide the local IP now check out https://www.whatismyip.com/ they know your internal ip address, also open this website using your mobile they knows your mobiles local ip address too.
EDIT: Im using JioFi Router, on mobile im using mobile data on Android 9 AOSP Based rom

Answer (score 13):

hostname(1) can tell the IP address: `hostname --ip-address`, or as man says, it's better to use `hostname --all-ip-addresses`

Answer (score 12):

It is very simple and above answers are complicating things. Simply you can get both local and public ip addresses  using this method.

```
   <?php 
$publicIP = file_get_contents("http://ipecho.net/plain");
echo $publicIP;

$localIp = gethostbyname(gethostname());
echo $localIp;

?>
```

Comment: Well this doesn't really work for me using Ubuntu and I have on my wlo1 a private ipv4 ip and that is what I need not the public. Yours is giving the public IP. And that surely is not what I know to be local IP address.The question is about local IP.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this php code :

```
$localIP = getHostByName(getHostName());
  
// Displaying the address 
echo $localIP;
```

If you want get ipv4 of your system, Try this :

```
shell_exec("ip route get 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $7}'")
```

Answer (score 7):

You may try this as regular user in CLI on Linux host:

```
function get_local_ipv4() {
  $out = split(PHP_EOL,shell_exec("/sbin/ifconfig"));
  $local_addrs = array();
  $ifname = 'unknown';
  foreach($out as $str) {
    $matches = array();
    if(preg_match('/^([a-z0-9]+)(:\d{1,2})?(\s)+Link/',$str,$matches)) {
      $ifname = $matches[1];
      if(strlen($matches[2])>0) {
        $ifname .= $matches[2];
      }
    } elseif(preg_match('/inet addr:((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3})\s/',$str,$matches)) {
      $local_addrs[$ifname] = $matches[1];
    }
  }
  return $local_addrs;
}

$addrs = get_local_ipv4();
var_export($addrs);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'eth0' => '192.168.1.1',
  'eth0:0' => '192.168.2.1',
  'lo' => '127.0.0.1',
  'vboxnet0' => '192.168.56.1',
)
```

Comment: `array('bond0'=>'10.66.42.83','bond1'=>'hosting Ip address','lo'=>'127.0.0.1', )` I got this. I added this code in php file,

Comment: Good answer, thanx. `split()` function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. so suggest using `explode()` instead

Answer (score 5):

```
$localIP = gethostbyname(trim(exec("hostname")));
```

I tried in Windows pc and Its worked and also think that Will work on Linux to.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy one. You can get the host name by this simple code.

```
$ip = getHostByName(getHostName());
```

Or you can also use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the hostname.

Answer (score 3):

```php
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In windows

```
$exec = 'ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv4.*"';
exec($exec, $output);
preg_match('/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/', $output[0], $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

For Windows:

```
exec('arp -a',$sa);
$ipa = [];
foreach($sa as $s)
    if (strpos($s,'Interface:')===0)
        $ipa[] = explode(' ',$s)[1];

print_r($ipa);
```

The **$ipa** array returns all local IPs of the system

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled with this question for a server-side php (running from Linux terminal)

I exploded 'ifconfig' and trimmed it down to the IP address.

Here it is:

```
$interface_to_detect = 'wlan0';
echo explode(' ',explode(':',explode('inet addr',explode($interface_to_detect,trim(`ifconfig`))[1])[1])[1])[0];
```

And of course change 'wlan0' to your desired network device.

My output is:

```
192.168.1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the public IP of your server:

```
$publicIP = getHostByName($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
echo $publicIP;

// or

$publicIP = getHostByName($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
echo $publicIP;
```

If none of these global variables are available in your system or if you are in a LAN, you can query an external service to get your public IP:

```
$publicIP = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org/');
echo $publicIP;

// or

$publicIP = file_get_contents('http://checkip.amazonaws.com/');
echo $publicIP;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a dev environment on OS X, connected via Wifi:

```
echo exec("/sbin/ifconfig en1 | grep 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Function to get all system ip(s) on PHP / Windows.

```
function GetIPs(){
    $sa = explode("\n",shell_exec('ipconfig'));
    $ipa = [];
    foreach($sa as $i){
        if (strpos($i,'IPv4 Address')!==false){
            $ipa[] = trim(explode(':', $i)[1]);
        }
    }
    return($ipa);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Local IPv4 Address, tested with RHEL:

```
function getLocalIPv4(){
    return str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r"),'',shell_exec("nmcli | grep inet4 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1 2>&1"));
}
```

Even better, tested with RHEL:

```
function getLocalIPv4(){
    return str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r", ' '),'',shell_exec('hostname -I 2>&1'));
}
```

Two things to note:

1. `array("\n", "\t", "\r")` you have to use quotes and not ticks, otherwise it won't remove the carriage return.  Not sure why....  `"\t"` not needed really....
2. This function is **meant for one interface**.

Answer (score 0):

if you have only one ip assigned to the server you can use the following code

```
$hostname = gethostname(); // Get the hostname of the current server
$host_ip = gethostbyname($hostname); // Get the primary IPv4 address associated with the hostname
```

or if there are multiple ips assigned to the server then you can use following

```
$host_ips = gethostbynamel(gethostname());
```

remember gethostbynamel returns an array of ips

Answer (score -4):

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

- `PHP_SELF`               Returns the filename of the current script with the path relative to the root
- `SERVER_PROTOCOL`        Returns the name and revision of the page-requested protocol
- `REQUEST_METHOD`         Returns the request method used to access the page
- `DOCUMENT_ROOT`          Returns the root directory under which the current script is executing

Comment: All true, but also all completely irrelevant to the question that was asked. -1.

Answer (score -6):

Try this

```
$localIP = gethostbyname(trim('hostname'));
```