# Get the IP address (192.168.X.X, assigned by the wireless router) in my webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, web

How do I get the inner IP address in my webpage? Can be any language for designing a website (javascript,php,etc.). What I need to do actually, is to make a local web server, and to let the clients in the same wifi network to connect via its shown IP address(192.168.X.X) on a webpage. But I always get 127.0.0.1 in php instead of 192.168.X.X, any ideas?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219178/php-how-to-get-local-ip-of-system which contains the same question.

Comment: When you run your page on your localhost you always get your localhost IP: 127.0.0.1

If you upload it to another server you can see your WAN IP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP how to get local IP of system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219178/php-how-to-get-local-ip-of-system)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved by the following code, getting the wireless local IP address(192.168.X.X):

```
$myIP = gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// PHP < 5.3.0
$Local_IP = @gethostbyname(php_uname('n'));

// PHP >= 5.3.0
$Local_IP = @gethostbyname(getHostName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the methods given above would flawlessly work on a live server but become a little bit of a menace when you use them on a local server and the least you get is the local IP `127.0.0.1`

I am not so sure about Windows or other Linux distros, but with Debian-based distros, you can use `exec()` to check it directly from the machine.

```
$serverIP = exec( "hostname -I" );
echo $serverIP;

# output: 192.168.X.X
```

**NOTE**: I do not recommend using this method on a live server, in fact it's highly advised that you disable the exec function on your live/production server

Answer (score -1):

You just have to read it in

```
$ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

If you want to know all data available in $_SERVER use:

```
print("<pre>\n");
print_r($_SERVER);
print("\n</pre>\n");
```

$_SERVER contains lots of useful informations. You may also want to check:

```
$_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR']
```

Comment: the server is using localhost, so it won't get the expected ip by using **$_SERVER**, it return 127.0.0.1 to me. thanks anyway.