# Get the private ip address at a specific ethernet port in PHP

Tags: php

I have the PHP coe running on a server. I want the IP address of the local system. This question has been asked before - [PHP how to get local IP of system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219178/php-how-to-get-local-ip-of-system)

When I use any of the solutions mentioned in the above post, I can only get the hostname, not the IP address.

e.g. on my machine I have

eth0:10.0.2.15 
eth1:192.168.1.115

When I run the following code:

```
$localIP = getHostByName(getHostName());
```

I only get the hostname - `localvm`. I want `192.168.1.115`

Can I get the private ip address? more specifically can I get the IP address at a specific port?

Comment: It depends on OS. What operating system are you running?

Comment: I am using Amazon linux and also Cent OS for local development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get IP address of a specific network port in Linux with something like:

```
function getInterfaceIP($interface = 'eth0')
{
        $interfaceCommand = "/sbin/ifconfig " . $interface . " | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }'";
        $output = exec($interfaceCommand);

        return $output;
}

echo getInterfaceIP('eth0');
```

Note that command syntax may differ from OS to OS. This example works for Linux. PHP doesn't have any built-in classes to do this.

You may want to add another command - getting a list of all network interfaces available ('ifconfig -s' provides those).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct. However, if someone is working on AWS cloud or Openstack, he can make use of the [cloud-init](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/datasources.html?highlight=169.254.169.254) tools (already present) and use the magic IP to retrieve the local ip address as follows:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4/
```