# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] returns 5 number long IP

Tags: php, ip

I am using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to log the user IP and then locate them.

However the number returned is like 19377 when full address is 193.77.xxx.xxx

How can I:

1. get the full IP
2. maintain the "." structure

Comment: It is impossible that the "." are gone. You must have other codes which affect the IP address. Show us.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19796250/4606122

Comment: Can you show your usage that is giving the integer?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!
I figured it out!

I needed to change the field type from 11 INT to 16 VARCHAR to accommodate the different characters.